# Is there an alternative to reference tables when using EF6 and SQL Server 2012?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a database with a number of reference tables such as ContentType where the table has just two columns Id and Name. These reference tables provide the data for Foreign Keys such as in the Content table and they are used in Where clauses quite often

We're using code first but hand coding the SQL ourselves and not using the database migrate features.

Is there an alternative to putting this data into a reference table that might have only 2 or 3 rows. Something that would still work with EF6 or 6.1. Note that I would still like to keep the data separate and not mix data for example I don't want to mix the data for WorkType in the same table as ContentType.

Comment: Are you using `Enum`s currently or is that where you want to get to? Also are you using Code First (wring the code out by hand) or Database First (using the designer view with a `.edmx` file) model?

Comment: We are using code first but creating our own SQL and not using the model to update the database.  No we are not using Enums? Is that an approach we could take and does that mean the Enum is created in the database and I could join to it ?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do it using Code First (I have only done it with the designer) but I know for sure EF supports mapping two column tables like you are describing in to a C# `Enum`. If you figure out how to do it feel free to post an answer to your own question explaining how to do it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve or what is bothering you related to the current implementation? Is it just the fact that there are tables that only have 2 or 3 rows?

Comment: I have a large number of tables with 2-3 rows. So just want to be sure if there are any other options for storing that data in the database other than combining all into one table and having a rowType column.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the reference table you're seeking would be something that would tell you what table contains the ContentTypes and what table contains the WokTypes in order to generalize the way you fetch records based on their types whether they're Content or Work etc? I don't know how that would work for you since you are using native SQL and have to define your foreign keys between Content-->ContentType and Work-->WorkType (it is how it should be done) and perform joins using them. Care to elaborate a little more on what is it you're trying to achieve? maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Why do you need to join to the reference tables anyway? Hopefully not to extract the name string because that seems like a violation of separation of concerns. Generating strings for display should not happen in database-related code.

Comment: Large number of Tables with 2-3 rows is certainly not a good design. I would suggest creating a hierarchical config items with ConfigID, Name, Value, Type (ContentType,WorkItemType etc etc) and a nullable ParentConfigID which you can use to create hierarchical structure to visually navigate and query.

Comment: Simple database design error you should avoid #1 https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just use these tables as lookups you can replace them with Enums as Scott Chamberlain suggested. You can do it with Entity Framework Code First like this:

```
public enum ContentType
{
    Text,
    Image,
    Video,
    Audio,
}

public class Content
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ContentType { get; set; }
}

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }

     public static List<Content> GetImages()
     {
          using (var context = new TestContext()
          {
               return context.Contents
                             .Where(c => c.ContentType == ContentType.Image)
                             .ToList();              
          }
     }
}
```

Using enums of course has the disadvantage that you have to recompile your application to extend or change them, so database lookups give you more flexibility.